# NLog stopped recording logs to database for Azure App

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, nlog

I've got two azure apps that both use NLog to record logs to a Azure SQL database.  Both have been running since November 2019.

On June 30, one app stopped logging while the other continues to function - they log to the same DB.  There have been no recent changes to the app that stopped logging.  The connection string it uses is the same one the it uses for database connectivity.  So other than logging, the app is working.

I've verified the database user can successfully call the logging procedure in Azure SQL DB.  I've also successfully run a local unit test against the production database to trigger logging.

1. DB user can invoke DB proc for logging (yes)
2. Application can connect and perform necessary CRUD ops (yes)
3. NLog uses same connection string as other DB calls (yes)
4. Locally run master branch code logs successfully (yes)
5. No changes in over four months to either code or database (confirmed)

How can the application function for every database call except for logging?
<strike>Could azure see frequent logging as an attack on the database from the app?  If so, how could it tell the difference between an NLog proc call and everything else?</strike>

Thanks for looking

Comment: What nuget-package are you using to make NLog write to the Azure DB? Have you checked the NLog InternalLogger output ?

Comment: @RolfKristensen NLog version 4.5.2.  I've not checked internalLogger.  I'll look into that.  thanks!

Comment: @RolfKristensen Enabling the internal logger reset the application service.  This apparently cleared the issue with logging to the DB.  Another detail is that the secondary target in fallback group was able to log.  Unfortunately I cannot determine the root cause.

Answer (score 0):

Restarting the app services corrected the logging issue.  If it happens again, I'll try to find the root cause of the problem.